# Is there any way to set Java system properties in a .jar file so that they have default values but can be overridden at the command line?

Tags: java, configuration

Is there any way to set Java system properties in a .jar file (e.g. via the JAR manifest) so that they have default values but can be overridden at the command line?

For example, suppose I wanted to set the system property `foo.bar` to `haha`:

```
 java -jar myprog.jar
```

would default `foo.bar` to `haha` but

```
 java -D foo.bar=hoho -jar myprog.jar
```

would set `foo.bar` to `hoho`.

---

Update: This should not touch the system args used in main(String[] args).

Comment: I dont think there will  be default value because if there is default definition exist for system property there is no need to take -option .you can set programmatically as a default

Comment: Does it have to be core Java solution?

Comment: What sort of application is this? There are some toolkits (e.g., Spring) that provide this functionality as part of the library, but otherwise you're down to defining defaults and overwriting them yourself.

Comment: according I have read there is system.c file native code which is setting system properties at run time ...

Answer (score 0):

If you run this using: `java -jar myprog.jar foo.bar=hoho` typing `args[0]` inside the main method will return `foo.bar=hoho` so we need to split it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     if(args[0].isEmpty) { // no first argument, so we will use the default value
          prop.setProperty("foo.bar", "haha");
     } else {

         String[] words = args[0].split("="); // split the argument where the = is
         prop.setProperty(words[0], words[1]);

     }

}
```

The above code doesn't load the property file, I hope you get the basic idea, good luck!

Comment: I need to not touch the main() args.

Answer (score 0):

Create a properties file containing your default values. [This link shows how to work with Java properties files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html).

Since the command line properties will already be available in your application's System.properties (e.g. `-Dtest=bart`), and since the command line properties need to be overridden by the properties in the properties file, you could do something like this:

This simple class will read the properties from myprop.properties, and place the key/value into System.properties. If the property already exists in System.properties because the property was specified on the command line, the property will not be overwritten.

```
package org.snb;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertiesTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InputStream in = PropertiesTester.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myprop.properties");

        Properties defaultProperties = new Properties();
        defaultProperties.load(in);

        for (Map.Entry<Object,Object> e : defaultProperties.entrySet()) {
            String overrideValue = defaultProperties.getProperty((String)e.getKey());
            if (null != overrideValue) {
                System.setProperty((String)e.getKey(), overrideValue);
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<Object,Object> e : System.getProperties().entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("key: " + e.getKey() + " value: " + e.getValue());
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

// myprop.properties

```
test=maggie
myval=homer
no-override=krusty
```

The command line should include:

```
-Dtest=bart -Dtest2=trump
```

- NOTE: there should be no space following the "-D" on the command
  line.
- NOTE that myprop.properties can be placed in the jar file.